# nested group by select in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am doing the following SELECT statement to see how many Reps each of my Manufacturers have in my database, this is working nicely:

```
SELECT ManufacturerId, COUNT(*) AS RepCount 
FROM ManufacturerSalesReps WHERE IsDeleted=0
GROUP BY ManufacturerID
ORDER BY  COUNT(*)
```

So this gives me the ManufacturerId and the number of reps but what i really need is the number of manufacturers at different rep counts.  So I want to GROUP the results from the above SELECT by RepCount.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of something else, but:

```
SELECT T.RepCount, COUNT(*) AS ManufacturerCount
FROM (
    SELECT ManufacturerId, COUNT(*) AS RepCount 
    FROM ManufacturerSalesReps
    WHERE IsDeleted=0
    GROUP BY ManufacturerID
) AS T
GROUP BY T.RepCount
ORDER BY  COUNT(*)
```

Either this is correct or totally dumb.

Answer (score 0):

With [windowing functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

```
SELECT ManufacturerId, COUNT(*), 
count(ManufacturerId) over (partition by COUNT(*)) num_man AS RepCount 
FROM ManufacturerSalesReps WHERE IsDeleted=0
GROUP BY ManufacturerID
ORDER BY  2
```